# How to dynamically show Rails fields based on a boolean field's state?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3 app using Jquery, I'm trying to dynamically show/ hide form elements, based on whether a boolean field is true or false.

At present my jquery function looks something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#boolean').change(function(){
        if ($(this).value == true) {
            $('.hidden-fields').show();
        } else {
            $('.hidden-fields').hide();
        }
    });
})
```

How do I correctly pass the boolean fields value into this function such that:

1. the function is initialized on page load, and fields hidden/shown
   based on the value in the database; and
2. the fields are toggled when the boolean is changed.

Sorry of this is a simple question. I'm trying to get to grips with javascript and really appreciate any pointers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only have one element on your HTML page with an **id** of boolean? Because using `#boolean` will return the first one only. If you have many, you should use a **class** of `boolean` instead, and then use `.boolean` to reference all elements with that class.

But to your questions:

1) Your example code there *will* be run on page load and will automatically apply to all elements with a .boolean class (assuming you go that way). If you want to immediately hide or show elements because, say, a value in the DB is set to `false`, then you should do that when you're rendering your page in your ERB or HAML or whatever view.

2) If the element you're attaching this JS to is a select box or something that will have a change() function, then you're all set to go. If you're wondering if, when the DB changes, this view automatically changes its visibility, then that is something different.

Comment: Hi mrDanA, thanks for your answer. 1) makes sense, of course - doh! I was getting too hung up on the javascript. 2) #boolean is a single checkbox. If true, a numer of subsequent fields should be shown, all with class .hidden-fields. The state of #boolean does not seem to be passed into the function at present. Clicking #boolean hides the .hidden-fields, but they do not reappear on subsequent clicks. Any ideas?

Comment: or perhaps I have the wrong syntax for the true state? Either way the `if boolean is true` part of the function is not working as expected

Comment: I've currently taken the conditional statement out of the function, and simply using a toggle(). Not the ideal solution, but its working for now. I'd still like to get the conditional working if anyone has any ideas on the syntax. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for a late reply. For the boolean true part, try `$(this).val() == "true"`.

Comment: Hi MrDanA, this is now working for the `if true` part of the function, but the `else` is not working! i.e., this statement always returns true. I'm very confused!

Comment: I could not get the conditional statement to work as I wanted. I'm currently using a toggle() function. This is working to solve the question I asked, but I was hoping to build additional functions into the conditional. Thanks MrDanA for helping me get this far.